# angularjs - ng-include dynamic position

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There are 8 divs positioned as 4 per row. When i click on any of the first 4 divs my dynamic template ( via ng-include ) should be placed after 4th div. And when i click on any of next 4 divs dynamic template should be placed after 8th div.

I dont know how to do this in angularjs. Should i use jquery for dom manipulation to find the clicked div position index and then create the ng-include div to place the content? Here's what i tried with jquery and angularjs.

```
<div ng-controller="collegeCtrl" ng-repeat="college in colleges">
    <div class="stepBlock" ng-click="goToView(college.viewname);">
        <img ng-src="{{college.logo ? college.logo : defaultcollegelogo}}" alt="">
        <h4><span class="color-dark-gray">{{college.name}}</span></h4>
    </div>

 </div>
```

and my controller code

```
app.controller("collegeCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.colleges = [
     {name:'...', logo:'...', viewname:'...'},
     /*.... and 7 more ....*/
    ];
    $scope.goToView = function(viewname){
        $('div.placeHolderDiv').remove();
        var stepBlock = $('.stepBlock'); var stepPos = this.$index;
        var placeHolderDiv = stepBlock.eq(stepPos < 4 ? 3 : stepBlock.length-1);
        var _view = $('<div class="placeHolderDiv"><div ng-include="\'tmpl-view-'+viewname + '\'"  onload="onViewLoad()"></div></div>');
        var _compiled = $compile(_view)($scope);
        _compiled.insertAfter(placeHolderDiv).hide().fadeIn();
    };
    $scope.onViewLoad = function(){
        alert('view loaded');
    };
 });
```

**Update : i've managed to create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HmozDuLv55LPcCNGPnHJ?p=preview)** ( sorry, i'm not good at CSS but you will get the idea)

Is this something hard to do with angular only?

Comment: manipulating DOM through controller, looks like code smell

Comment: I know, is there any better way to do for something like this?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like google image preview?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do like this for lets say div 2:
`<div ng-show="showDiv[1]" ng-include="{{view}}">`
in your main template, and then change the ng-click for div 2 to something like: `ng-click="showView(1, college.viewname)"` and in your controllor:

```
showDiv = [];

$scope.showView = function (divNr, viewname) {
    $scope.view = 'tmpl-view-' + viewname;
    showDiv[divNr] = true;
}
```

Comment: As i'm using ng-repeat, i dont want to have more than one ng-include my repeat directive when it renders

Comment: Don't really have time to check this, but doest the content change when `$scope.view` changes? That way changing the viewname would be sufficient?